# Does anyone know how to setup the latest playframe work project with Quill

Tags: scala, playframework, quill.io

I running 2.12/play2.7 project and would like to use Quill.io as the database layer. Does anyone know how to set up such a combination?

I tried to use the https://github.com/getquill/play-quill-jdbc as starting point, but could not get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to add it as a dependency? https://github.com/getquill/quill#sbt-dependencies-19

Comment: yep, i added ```libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.8",
  "io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "3.4.10-SNAPSHOT"
)```